# Pass the triggered element to the bootbox callback jquery

Tags: jquery, callback, element, bootbox

I want to pass the 'a.delete' triggered element to my bootbox callback, is there a way to do that?

```
var confirm = false;
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    if( confirm == false){ e.preventDefault(); }
    bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", function(result) {
        if(result == true){
            confirm = true;
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Well, Taplar I did what you said, but isn't triggering the action, even if the "trigger click" is working...

```
var confirm = false;
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    if( confirm == false){
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", function(result) {
            if(result == true){
                confirm = true;
                console.log(confirm);
                element.trigger('click');
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('triggered again');
    }
});
```

**EXIT**: What I get after clicking the confirm button

```
true

triggered again
```

**My Solution**

```
var confirm = false;
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    var element = $(this);
    if( confirm == false){
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Confirm?", function(result) {
            if(result == true){
                confirm = true;
                $(element)[0].click();
            }
        });
    } else {confirm = false;}
});
```

Comment: Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish here? It looks like you're using a hyperlink as a delete button, and confirming that the request should proceed?

Comment: Yeah, if the bootbox is confirmed then proceed with it natural behaviour, that's it... I was asking because it seems that bootbox doesn't have an option to pass parameters... anyways I solved it(How I thought was right) :D

Answer (score 1):

Before you call bootbox.confirm, store "this" in a varaible.

```
var clickedElement = this;
```

Then inside bootbox.confirm you can reference "clickedElement".

Comment: I guess I have to ask, what your expecting element.trigger('click') to do.  From your logic, that result is expected.

Comment: I want 'element.trigger('click')' to execute the initial href action of the 'a' tag...Instead of asking the confirmation again(This if you said yes to the bootbox confirm).

Comment: Is it not doing this?  From your OP, it will only do the else if it was previously confirmed.  As your console is writing out the text from the else, it is following into that logic.  And since you are only preventing the event and asking for confirmation inside the preceeding if, the second event should continue on with whatever it would normally do.

Comment: No, is not continuing the action, that's why I tested it doing that "else" with the log in it, cuz is doing nothing.

Comment: Unsure in that case.  My assumption at that point then would be that something else is preventing the action.  Without a working example, I don't feel strongly that I can offer more advice.

Comment: Finally got the solution, thx for the help Taplar. I edited my post with the solution

Answer (score 0):

While what you have may "work", you really don't want to use a hyperlink for a delete action. By doing so, you're using a GET request to trigger a change on the server end (and a destructive one at that), which is supposed to be [a bit of a no-no](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

A better solution is to swap out your hyperlinks with individual forms for actual buttons, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="your/deleteaction" class="delete-item">
    <input name="ID" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form.delete-item', function(e) {
    bootbox.confirm("Really delete this item?", function(result) {
        if(result !== true){
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });
});
```

In this way, you're following best practice, and you're using the bootbox confirm as an escape clause, instead of having to re-trigger the link.